# Nagios check_http - checking tomcat application status with regex & linespan

Tags: tomcat, regex, nagios

I wan't to check with our Nagios if a webapplication is running on Tomca7. I decided to use the check_http plugin with regex. I'm parsing the status-page of tomcat and check if column "Running" is true. The Sourcecode of the status-page looks like this (snipped):

```
<td class="row-left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" rowspan="2"><small>Applicationname</small></td>
<td class="row-center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" rowspan="2"><small>true</small></td>
```

The 2 informations are in 2 different lines.
So my line to check is the folowing:

```
./check_http -I 111.111.111.111 -p 8080 -a user:password -u /manager/html -rl 'Applicationname</small></td>\n.<td class="row-center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" rowspan="2"><small>true'
```

The problem is, that the response of the plugin is always true ("HTTP OK") when I'm using the parameter "-l". Also when I modify the search-string like this to force a critical:

```
./check_http -I 111.111.111.111 -p 8080 -a user:password -u /manager/html -rl 'Applicationname</small></td>\n.<td class="row-center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" rowspan="2"><small>fail_true'
```

I have no idea why this happaned. Someone any idea? Thanks, Arny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use the `/manager/text/list` to see the plain text manager interface instead of the HTML interface:

```
./check_http -I 111.111.111.111 -p 8080 -a user:password -u /manager/text/list -s 'Applicationname:running'

HTTP OK: HTTP/1.1 200 OK - 510 bytes in 0.003 second response time |time=0.003004s;;;0.000000 size=510B;;;0
```

Comment: Yes, that was also an idea, but it seems, that the text-page don't work. On /manager/list you get a 404 error: `The Manager application has been re-structured[..] /manager/text for the text interface`. On /manager/text I get also a error: `FAIL - Unknown command /text`. The catalina.out says nothing.

Comment: [Tomcat 7](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#List_Currently_Deployed_Applications) has changed the plain-text manager interface to `/manager/text/list`.

Comment: Yea, I think I can work with this Info. Very thanks!

Answer (score 0):

from the man page [check_http](http://nagiosplugins.org/man/check_http) "-s, --string=STRING String to expect in the content"
have you try with "-s" ?

```
$  ./check_http  -I localhost -p 80 -s True -u /test.html
HTTP CRITICAL: HTTP/1.1 200 OK - string 'True' not found on 'http://localhost:80/test.html' -    419 bytes in 0.001 second response time |time=0.000667s;;;0.000000 size=419B;;;0

$  ./check_http  -I localhost -p 80 -s true -u /test.html
HTTP OK: HTTP/1.1 200 OK - 419 bytes in 0.001 second response time |time=0.000776s;;;0.000000    size=419B;;;0

$  cat /var/www/html/test.html 
<td class="row-left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" rowspan="2"><small>Applicationname</small></td>
<td class="row-center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" rowspan="2"><small>true</small></td>
```

Comment: The problem is, that "true" several times match, because there are running some more Webapps on this tomcat. Sorry for the missing info.